# How to use VBA to show / hide multiple combinations of tables in MS Word? - explained further within

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word 2010 document with some basic VBA code attached to a number checkboxs that show / hide a sections throughout the document.
There are a number of these throughout the document however they all share the same basic code which appears to be working well enough (example below)

```
Private Sub PlanningBox_Click()
If PlanningBox.Value = False Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Planning").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Else
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Planning").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

The issue i am having is that some of these sections then have checkboxes within them that show / hide further section which is fine, however if the user unchecks the first initial checkbox (hiding all sections) then re-checks it, it will open up the initial section again but not the ticked subsections - in order to do this they have to uncheck/check the subsection again. I know this seems minor but i need to ensure the form is as fluid and user acessible as possible..

For example let's say there is a single row table with the text 'Have you spoken to anyone for feedback?' (checkbox1) - the user will tick the check box which will unhide a section of text below giving directions, asking some questions, general blurb etc. At the bottom of this is another question 'Who did you speak to?" - and then multiple checkboxes 'mother','father', 'Child' (checkbox A,B,C,etc). Checking any of these boxes opens up a table with additional questions for each one selected, the user can check any number / combination of the checkboxes.

Now if the user unchecks the initial checkbox 1. all sections will be hidden no problem, but then if they then check it to reveal the section again the mother, father etc boxes remain ticked but will not reveal the sections without needing to be unticked/ticked again. Is there a way so that ticking the intial box will also reveal any previously unhidden sections again?

My knowledge of VBA is very limited, i have considered using If + ElseIF statements but my understanding is that i would need an ElseIf for every potential combination. Is there a more sophisticated way around this at all?

Hopefully i have articulated this well enough but happy to provide further information. Thank you for any assistance given

Comment: It looks like nothing in the `PlanningBox_Click` procedure persists the state taken from the checkbox.  It's completely relying on the state of `Range.Font.Hidden` which is becoming `True` when its parent range is hidden.

Comment: Is there a way to have the parent range checkbox evaluate the value of the sub-section checkboxes and show these ranges if true without having to write an If statement for every possible combination?

Comment: For one way to do that, you could create a common routine that evaluates every checkbox. See my proposed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a common routine that evaluates every checkbox and sets the corresponding section accordingly. Call that one routine whenever a checkbox is clicked.

```vb
Private Sub PlanningBox_Click()
    SetRangeVisibility
End Sub

Private Sub SomeOtherBox_Click()
    SetRangeVisibility
End Sub

Public Sub SetRangeVisibility()
    If PlanningBox.Value = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Planning").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Planning").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If

    If SomeOtherBox.Value = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SomeOtherRange").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SomeOtherRange").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If

    ' Etc...

End Sub
```

Further, if you use an array of check boxes you'd only need to write a single `SomeBox_Click` event procedure. Here is some information on [Control Arrays in VBA](https://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/).

Comment: Why isn't this great reply accepted as answer?